# Underscore '_.map' and styling in Javascript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, underscore.js

I'm mapping through each item in my JSON object for my 'work' section of my personal website.

[image]

What I want is to just have one single "Work" on the left col-xs-3 and then list out the rest of the work details on the right hand side of col-xs-9. I have duplicates of 'Work' because obviously, I'm mapping through it however many job details I have listed. This seems relatively simple to solve, but I can't wrap my head around how to do this.

```
workList(item) {
    return (
        <section>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-3">
                    <div className="about-title">
                        <h1>Work</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-xs-9">
                    <div className="about-body">
                        <h3>{item.company}</h3>
                        <h4>{item.position}</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            {_.chain(this.props.work).map(this.workList).value()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I tried to take the col-xs-3 out of `workList()` and put it in `render()` but something got screwed up and the whole styling was off :( any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how does `this.props.work` look like? why do you call `value()`?

Comment: I could've just used `.map` but `.chain().value()` works pretty much the same way. `this.props.work` gives me access to the JSON object that contains information about my work - location, company, position, etc.